# String ISIN another data frame returns nothing

Tags: python

I have a dataframe `DF`

| Name | Code | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 1 | red |
| Test2 | 1 | blue |
| Test3 | 2 | red |
| Test4 | 3 | blue |
| Test5 | 3 | black |

I did the following code :

```
DFN = DF.loc[DF['Code'].isin(['1'])].reset_index(drop=True)
DFCode = DF.loc[DF['Color'].isin(DFN['Color'].values.tolist())].reset_index(drop=True)
```

This does return nothing, what am I doing wrong ?
The output excepted would be :

| Name | Code | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 1 | red |
| Test2 | 1 | blue |
| Test3 | 2 | red |
| Test4 | 3 | blue |

Note : I don't know the color that I will be looking for and this is why I need to identify the Colors using the `Code` Column

Comment: `Code` is probably integers, so you need to check if the value `isin([1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments already suggested, you need to check if the values in the `Code` columns are integers or strings. Probably there is the problem.

If you just look for one value you can just filter with `==`, no need for `isin`.

Use [`pandas.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) to check for all occuring values in a column, it's just a little more straightforward than `values.tolist()`.

```
DFN = DF[DF['Code']==1] # or DFN = DF[DF['Code']=='1']
DFCode = DF.loc[DF['Color'].isin(DFN['Color'].unique())]
print(DFCode)

    Name  Code Color
0   Test     1   red
1  Test2     1  blue
2  Test3     2   red
3  Test4     3  blue
```